# Ubuntu Server 23.10 compatible USB Wireless WIFI Adapter

Tags: networking

I'm new to this.
During an install of Ubuntu server 23.10, I was unable to
get Ubuntu server to recognized my wireless USB WIFI adapter.

The adapter is a USB RALINK TECHNOLOGY LLC, MT7601U wireless
WIFI adapter.

I have 2 Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon machines that recognizes those wireless
WIFI adapters but Ubuntu Server 23.10 doesn't.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Please run the command `lsusb` and edit your question to include the output. Thanks. Also, on a blank line above the output please put ``` and on the blank line below the output, another ``` and this will format the output as code. Reply back with @mchid if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

If the adapter is plugged into the computer's USB socket before starting
the server software installation the adapter will not recognize no matter
how long one waits at the network configuration step.

The key to having the RALINK wireless WIFI adapter recognized is to wait
to plug the adapter into the computer's USB port until the network
configuration step occurs. Once the adapter is recognized, perform the
configuration and select Save. If the computer's RJ-45 ethernet socket
is not used, disable it. At this point select Done to move on to the next
server software installation step.

Thanks for the support.